# ValueError: shapes (20,14) and (13,1) not aligned: 14 (dim 1) != 13 (dim 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, gradient-descent

```
def  cal_cost(theta,X,y):
    m = len(y)    
    predictions = X.dot(theta)
    cost = (1/2*m) * np.sum(np.square(predictions-y))
    return cost

def minibatch_gradient_descent(X,y,theta,learning_rate=0.01,iterations=10,batch_size =20):
    m = len(y)
    cost_history = np.zeros(iterations)
    #n_batches = int(m/batch_size)

    for it in range(iterations):
        cost =0.0
        indices = np.random.permutation(m)
        X = X[indices]
        y = y[indices]
        for i in range(0,m,batch_size):
            X_i = X[i:i+batch_size]
            y_i = y[i:i+batch_size]

            X_i = np.c_[np.ones(len(X_i)),X_i]

            prediction = np.dot(X_i,theta)

            theta = theta -(1/m)*learning_rate*( X_i.T.dot((prediction - y_i)))
            cost += cal_cost(theta,X_i,y_i)
        cost_history[it]  = cost

    return theta, cost_history

theta = np.zeros((X_train.shape[1], 1))
minibatch_gradient_descent(X_train,y_train,theta)
```

When i run the above code i am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: shapes (20,14) and (13,1) not aligned: 14 (dim 1) != 13 (dim 0)
```

X_train.shape is (404,13) and y_train.shape is (404,1). I am updating the value of theta but it still gives me the error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're error occurs in `prediction = np.dot(X_i,theta)`. If you check the shape of `X_i`, it will print out `(20,14)`. Likewise if you check the shape of `theta`, it will print out `(13,1)`. Now you can see why you cannot take the dot product of `X_i` & `theta`. Since you've added an additional column to `X_i` using `X_i = np.c_[np.ones(len(X_i)),X_i]` its dimensions have changed ( Originally it was (20,13) ). So you need to add an additional row to your `theta` array to make the dimension of `theta` as `(14,1)`.